# Implementing strategy pattern in XQuery, reflection functions in general

Tags: xquery, marklogic, strategy-pattern

I wonder if there is a way to introspect XQuery modules and dynamically access functions. This would help me to implement the GOF strategy pattern as XQuery does not have support for multiple implementations for the same interface.

The problem, of course, is that there seems to be no support for introspection in XQuery except for checking for types of variables.

Any ideas on how this pattern can be implemented in XQuery? (I use MarkLogic 9)

thanks a lot,
K.

PS. Unfortunately, most XQuery resources I could find focus on small details of this or that functionality but I could not find one such resource that takes XQuery as a serious programming language on its own right and addresses such software design issues

Comment: Many of the common design patterns assume a mostly object-oriented view of the world. XQuery is decidedly functional. If you describe more concretely what you’re trying to accomplish, someone may be able to direct you to an appropriate functional pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XQuery 3.0+ and MarkLogic 9 support first-class functions. In many cases, you can rework common OO design patterns into functional programming equivalents using first-class functions and dependency injection.

Also, you can access in-scope functions via `xdmp:functions()`.

There is a way to get reflection-like functionality in ML, but it's kind of a hack. Take a look at this library, which throws an exception, catches it, and uses the exception payload to inspect the stack:

https://github.com/marklogic/cq/blob/master/lib-debug.xqy

For more XQuery programming patterns and techniques, you might want to review the proceedings from various XML-oriented conferences like [Balisage](https://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/index.html), [XML Prague](http://www.xmlprague.cz/archive/), and [XML London](http://xmllondon.com/). Also, searching GitHub repos for XQuery projects and reading code can be helpful.

Comment: XQuery 3.1 also offers the function load-xquery-module() which takes the a library module as input and returns references to the functions defined in the module.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I suppose I'd need to wait for ML to implement dynamic module loading, until then I'll stick with passing identifiers for strategies and storing functions in a map with these identifiers.